# Difference between gst_bus_add_watch() and g_signal_connect()

Tags: c, gstreamer, glib

I'm reading the GStreamer application developer manual, which talks about the pipeline bus in the context of message handling / event handling, they talk about 2 functions: gst_bus_add_watch() and g_signal_connect(). It appears that these 2 functions are interchangeable. The application manual says:

> Note that if you’re using the default GLib mainloop integration, you can, instead of attaching a watch,
>   connect to the “message” signal on the bus.

In page 27. What's the difference between these 2 functions, and in what contexts are they useful? Who uses the callbacks that we register in these functions? Does the element itself call the callbacks?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using gst_bus_add_watch() then you provide a callback that will be called when a message is available.

If you call gst_bus_add_signal_watch() then that registers a default callback that will register a GSource to the main-loop. This enables the use of signals.

It is functionality wise equivalent, but if you are e.g. writing a glib/gtk based app, using signal everywhere might give your code more consistency.

Comment: I asked about g_signal_connect(), not gst_bus_add_signal_watch(). Are these 2 functions equivalent?

Comment: They are not the same but the effect is similar. I pointed out gst_bus_add_signal_watch(), because you cannot use g_signal_connect() without having called gst_bus_add_signal_watch().

Comment: I've tried using both methods on a rtsp server implementation and using `gst_bus_add_signal_watch()` is giving me more feedback about registering watches