# gstreamer pipeline EOS issues

Tags: gstreamer

I'm writing a program to mimic a gsteramer pipeline I have working from the command line.

I have been able to successfully trap some signals like:

```
g_signal_connect (data2.source, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (pad_added_handler), &data2);
g_signal_connect (data2.source, "drained", G_CALLBACK (eos_cb), &data);
```

to add pads and tell when the url reader has reached end of stream — EOS.

I'm trying create a trap to find when the bus has reached EOS but am having issues.  I've seen examples of trapping errors from the bus like this:

```
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus), "message::error", (GCallback)error_cb, &data);
```

I'm thinking something like this should work:

```
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus), "message::eos", (GCallback)eos_cb_bus, &data);
```

But I do not know exactly what to look for (the 'message::eos' part).

Can someone help me? Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

The GStreamer hello world example is a good start to see how this should be handled:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/helloworld.html

Basically you set up a GstBus callback and pick the messages from there which you are interested in. In your case it will be EOS.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your code with [How to use a bus](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/bus.html#how-to-use-a-bus).  Copying the example code from there:

```
bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline);
gst_bus_add_signal_watch (bus);
g_signal_connect (bus, "message::error", G_CALLBACK (cb_message_error), NULL);
g_signal_connect (bus, "message::eos", G_CALLBACK (cb_message_eos), NULL);
```

So "message::eos" is the correct signal name.  Possibly you forgot [gst_bus_add_signal_watch()](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstBus.html#gst-bus-add-signal-watch) in your code?

Compare also [Difference between gst_bus_add_watch() and g_signal_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220063/difference-between-gst-bus-add-watch-and-g-signal-connect#37244376).